# MySQL Silent Install error: More than one package matches 'server;5.7.18' and the silent flag was given

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to write a batch script to install an instance of MySQL server onto a clean Windows virtual machine. While I'm attempting this with command line instructions, Powershell is also an OK solution also.

The problem I'm having is using the `MySQLInstallerConsole.exe` I just can't figure out the parameters to pass in order to get the server installed.

Batch File:

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "mysql-installer-community-5.7.19.0.msi" /qn

echo Configurating MySQL Server...
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows" 
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe install 
 server;5.7.19.0:*:port=3306;serverid=2:type=developer;username=root;password=root;role=DBManager

echo Installation was successfully
pause
```

Output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows>MySQLInstallerConsole.exe install server;5.7.18:*:port=3306;serverid=2:type=developer;username=root;password=root;role=DBManager -silent
=================== Start Initialization ===================
MySQL Installer is running in Commercial mode

Attempting to update manifest.
Initializing product requirements
Loading product catalog
Checking for product catalog snippets
Checking for product packages in the bundle
Categorizing product catalog
Finding all installed packages.
Your product catalog was last updated at 7/25/2017 11:33:18 AM
=================== End Initialization ===================

More than one package matches 'server;5.7.18' and the silent flag was given.  
Skipping.
Unable to find any products that match server;5.7.18
```

Comment: I think you just need to specify the architecture (x86/x64) like so: `server;5.7.19.0;x64:*:port=3306;;serverid=...`

Comment: unfortunately not the issue, I have solved two problems thus far, one is specifying a community edition install ie  MySQLInstallerConsole.exe community install etc and also it became apparent that I had no C++ redistributable package installed. Still after these two issues are solved it dosnt install, much less silently.